# Separate value by name and print as a query formate javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I Am trying to print the data in a div as below Expected output by using name say i have two input by name firstname and and last name and they are repeated three times am not able to print the data of the form as i expect am not sure how to do this.
Example:
Mickey1 and Mouse1 are in a first row so they should be printed in a div **as ('Mickey1','Mouse1')** and as there is a another row below that so a **","** should be added and the second row data should be added   **('Mickey2','Mouse2')** this should loop until there are new row below then at last print the **","** should not be added

Expected output: ('Mickey1','Mouse1'),('Mickey2','Mouse2'),('Mickey3','Mouse3')

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/crbbb8Ld/1/)

HTML:

```
<form id="Form" onsubmit="return false;">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>First name:
                <input type="text" name="FirstName" value="Mickey1">
            </td>
            <td>Last name:
                <input type="text" name="Lastname" value="Mouse1">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>First name:
                <input type="text" name="FirstName" value="Mickey2">
            </td>
            <td>Last name:
                <input type="text" name="Lastname" value="Mouse2">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>First name:
                <input type="text" name="FirstName" value="Mickey3">
            </td>
            <td>Last name:
                <input type="text" name="Lastname" value="Mouse3">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" onclick="Get();" />
<div id="data"></div>
```

JS:

```
function Get() {
        var Form = document.getElementById('Form');
        for (I = 0; I < Form.length; I++) {

            var Value = Form[I].value;
            alert('value' + Value);

            $('#data').text(Value);
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you want 3 groups of inputs (by lines), you need to loop through the lines, not the inputs.

Comment: Can you please share more clarity on this with the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why you need those values in this format exactly but here is the working code.

If you just need the values, but not to present them to the user I recommend to use JSON format and `.serialize()` function.

```js
function Get() {
  var html = '';
  var arr = [];
  $('tr').each(function() {
    var inputs = $('input', this);
    arr.push('("' + inputs[0].value + '","' + inputs[1].value + '")');
  });
  
  html = 'INSERT INTO demo (xxxx, xxxxx, xxxx,xxxx,xxxx) VALUES ' + arr.join(',') + ';';
  $('#data').html(html);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="Form" onsubmit="return false;">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>First name:
                <input type="text" name="FirstName" value="Mickey1">
            </td>
            <td>Last name:
                <input type="text" name="Lastname" value="Mouse1">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>First name:
                <input type="text" name="FirstName" value="Mickey2">
            </td>
            <td>Last name:
                <input type="text" name="Lastname" value="Mouse2">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>First name:
                <input type="text" name="FirstName" value="Mickey3">
            </td>
            <td>Last name:
                <input type="text" name="Lastname" value="Mouse3">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" onclick="Get();" />
<div id="data"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply and support  am trying to create this format as later i vl make this as a insert query to insert the value in sqlite database  am new to this  and you are right am not presenting this to user and i am not sure how to use jason

Comment: i have a issue on above after lite change `('Mickey1','Mouse1'),('Mickey2','Mouse2'),('Mickey3','Mouse3'),` code changed line  `html += "('" + inputs[0].value + "','" + inputs[1].value + "'),";` idata of output should look like above but the last coma should be removed

Comment: Oh, don't do this! You shouldn't send a server side (or "database side") queries directly from the client. Send parameters to the server and then build a query to the database!

Comment: can you help me on that ?? at the end i want a query like `"INSERT INTO demo (xxxx, xxxxx, xxxx,xxxx,xxxx) VALUES ('Mickey1','Mouse1'),('Mickey2','Mouse2'),('Mickey3','Mouse3')";`

Comment: Where as the insert and all will be in a variable i just need to create the value statement

Comment: Do you send this request to the server? Which language do you program?

Comment: to be simple am not communicating to any server am creating a mobile application where the mobile by itself has a sqlite database where am just running the "JAVASCRIPT" to insert the data i have a query which will insert the data that is just of  a single variable(s) when the array of data needs to be added as a row wise the above  query does i  just need the value of them in a that format

Comment: I updated my code so it will return the result you want.

Comment: Need some help Can i have your some of the time

Comment: i Have a condition were the last row of the table will be always empty and on same if there is single row the button should be disable the my design is same as Grid view Where the last row is always left blank to enter data

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. I need a visible staff (like fiddle or image) to understand it. If you want, you can give me your email address and we will continue there.

Answer (score 0):

```js
    function Get() {

        var form = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
        for (var i = 0; i < form.length; i += 1) {
            var value = form[i].value;
            if (i == 0) {
                $("#data").append("(");
            } else if (i == 1) {
                $("#data").append(",");
            } else if (i == 2) {
                $("#data").append("),(");
            } else if (i == 3) {
                $("#data").append(",");
            } else if (i == 4) {
                $("#data").append("),(");
            } else if (i == 5) {
                $("#data").append(",");
            } else if (i == 6) {
                $("#data").append(")");
            }
            $("#data").append(value);    
        }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="Form" onsubmit="return false;">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>First name:
                <input type="text" name="FirstName" value="Mickey1">
            </td>
            <td>Last name:
                <input type="text" name="Lastname" value="Mouse1">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>First name:
                <input type="text" name="FirstName" value="Mickey2">
            </td>
            <td>Last name:
                <input type="text" name="Lastname" value="Mouse2">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>First name:
                <input type="text" name="FirstName" value="Mickey3">
            </td>
            <td>Last name:
                <input type="text" name="Lastname" value="Mouse3">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" onclick="Get()" />

<p id="data"></p>
```

This is my go, if someone know more efficient way than `if else` statements, please share :)

Comment: Sorry, changed name of function to lowercase **g**et and also this should be inside of your <script> tag and should work.

Comment: What about `Expected output: ('Mickey1','Mouse1'),('Mickey2','Mouse2'),('Mickey3','Mouse3')`? Not just `alert`.

Comment: Nop i was using alert to check is it working or not the jason data as suggested above by #Mosh Feu, or something i want is as i have Mentioned above the expected output is should look as above you asked

Comment: at the end i vl make a query like which insert the data into the database   `"INSERT INTO demo (xxxx, xxxxx, xxxx,xxxx,xxxx) VALUES ('Mickey1','Mouse1'),('Mickey2','Mouse2'),('Mickey3','Mouse3')";`

Comment: I went away sorry! :D 
This is one option,but im sure that there is something more eloquent-
https://jsfiddle.net/779tdpcc/1/

Comment: that ok but when a new row is added for that row the code does Works

Answer (score 0):

```
function Get() {
var Value="";
var tempValue="";
var Form = document.getElementById('Form');
for (I = 0; I < Form.length; I++) {
    if(I%2==0){
       tempValue="('"+Form[I].value+"','"+Form[I+1].value+"'),";
       Value = Value + tempValue;
    }
}
 $('#data').text(Value.substr(0,Value.length-1));
```

}

Comment: This will give you what you want to as output

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/crbbb8Ld/5/#&togetherjs=AJBVaeyHMO can you join me hear it is not working

Comment: Hi there, you forget to add one "}" at the end that's the reason you are not able to get the ans.